# How to switch between different tkinter canvases from a start-up page and return back to start-up page in sub-canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, frame

I have created a [start-up canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HtLq.png), which contains buttoms to shfit to two other sub-canvases. In addition, in those two sub-canvases, buttom to return to start-up canvas is created.  However, after I enter the [sub-canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fNYN.png), I fail to return to start-up canvas. That is to say, when I click the buttom to return to the start-up canvas, it will create a start-up canvas beside the sub-canvas instead of closing the subcanvas and shifting to the start-up canvas. Is there any way to switch between canvases and return to the main canvas? Thank you!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import re


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._Canvas= None
        self.switch_Canvas(StartUpPage)

    def switch_Canvas(self, Canvas_class):
        new_Canvas = Canvas_class(self)
        if self._Canvas is not None:
                self._Canvas.destroy()
        self._Canvas = new_Canvas
        self._Canvas.pack()

class StartUpPage(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Frame(self)
        tk.Label(self, text="Example").grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        tk.Button(self, text="Canvas1",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(PageOne)).grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        tk.Button(self, text="Canvas2",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(PageTwo)).grid(column = 0, row = 2)


class PageOne(tk.Canvas, tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        root = tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.frame1  = tk.Frame(root, width=430)
        self.frame1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
        tk.Label(self.frame1, text="First Canvas").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self.frame1, text="Back to start-up page",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(StartUpPage)).pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Canvas, tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        root = tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.frame2  = tk.Frame(root, width=430)
        self.frame2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
        tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Second Canvas").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self.frame2, text="Back to start-up page",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(StartUpPage)).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does _"I fail to return to start-up canvas"_ mean? How does it fail? Does the program crash? Does it switch to the wrong canvas? Does it throw an error? Also, there is an indentation error in the code you posted, can you please fix it?

Comment: Indent on `self._Canvas.destroy()` After running the code, my guess is you would like to switch between canvases (and create them in the first place), but the code is actually creating new canvases on each button invocation, is my guess correct?

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed the indentation error. My problem is just like what Space mentioned. I cannot return to the start-up canvas. Instead, I will keep creating start-up canvas beside my sub-canvas.

Comment: The solution seems pretty obvious: don't create a new instance of the canvas class in the function. Instead, create it once outside the function. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you @BryanOakley! I don't really know how to put canvas class outside the function. Could you explain that to me? Thank you! I have several frames built in each sub-canvas. I want to switch between different subcanvases from the start-up canvas.

Answer (score 1):

So, few things:

**First**: There's the wrong *parent/master* relationship in `PageOne` and `PageTwo` in

`def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):`

Since you're inheriting from `tk.Canvas`, the new instance of the class has parent `master` which in itself get's passed from

`SampleApp`'s `switchCanvas` as `Canvas_class(self)` meaning `master` is `.` or the (main/root) window.

But then (we're still inside `PageOne`) you're making `root = tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` which becomes `None` since initializers return `None`.

Then you're creating a new `Frame` whose parent is `root` which is `None`.

In short

- `PageOne` and `PageTwo` are (also) new instances of `Canvas` whose parent is the main window, or the instance made by `SampleApp`.
- `root` aka the `Frame`'s parent is `None` (Which I even don't know how that affects it when you position it by`self.frame1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)`)

Hence I assume you're trying to making `PageOne` and `PageTwo` instances of `Frame` and put a `Canvas` inside them.

*These are the few changes I made to the two classes*: Their instances are now both of (type) `tk.Frame` that contains the other widgets.

```py
class PageTwo(tk.Frame): # Sub-lcassing tk.Frame
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):

        # self is now an istance of tk.Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master, *args, **kwargs)

        # make a new Canvas whose parent is self.
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self,bg='yellow', width=430)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Second Canvas").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5) 
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Back to start-up page",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(StartUpPage))
        
        self.button.pack()

        # pack the canvas inside the self (frame).
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True) 

        #print('is instance',isinstance(self,tk.Frame))
```

**Second**: Keeping track of which instances/objects are created, instead of continuously spawning new ones. I decided to keep it simple and create an internal `dict`ionary whose keys are the classes of `StratUpPage`,`PageOne` or `PageTwo` meaning each class gets to have **one** instance that can be switched to.

```py
def switch_Canvas(self, Canvas_class):

        # Unless the dictionary is empty, hide the current Frame (_mainCanvas is a frame)
        if self._mainCanvas:
            self._mainCanvas.pack_forget()

        # Modification 2: is the Class type passed is a one we have seen before?
        canvas = self._allCanvases.get(Canvas_class, False)

        # if Canvas_class is a new class type, canvas is False
        if not canvas:
            # Instantiate the new class
            canvas = Canvas_class(self)
            # Store it's type in the dictionary
            self._allCanvases[Canvas_class] = canvas

        # Pack the canvas or self._mainCanvas (these are all frames)
        canvas.pack(pady = 60)
        # and make it the 'default' or current one.
        self._mainCanvas = canvas
```

**Entire Code**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import re

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._mainCanvas= None
        # The dictionary to hold the class type to switch to
        # Each new class passed here, will only have instance or object associated with it (i.e the result of the Key)
        self._allCanvases = dict()
        # Switch (and create) the single instance of StartUpPage
        self.switch_Canvas(StartUpPage)

    def switch_Canvas(self, Canvas_class):

        # Unless the dictionary is empty, hide the current Frame (_mainCanvas is a frame)
        if self._mainCanvas:
            self._mainCanvas.pack_forget()

        # is the Class type passed one we have seen before?
        canvas = self._allCanvases.get(Canvas_class, False)

        # if Canvas_class is a new class type, canvas is False
        if not canvas:
            # Instantiate the new class
            canvas = Canvas_class(self)
            # Store it's type in the dictionary
            self._allCanvases[Canvas_class] = canvas

        # Pack the canvas or self._mainCanvas (these are all frames)
        canvas.pack(pady = 60)
        # and make it the 'default' or current one.
        self._mainCanvas = canvas

class StartUpPage(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Frame(self) # Here the parent of the frame is the self instance of type tk.Canvas
        tk.Label(self, text="Example").grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        tk.Button(self, text="Canvas1",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(PageOne)).grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        tk.Button(self, text="Canvas2",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(PageTwo)).grid(column = 0, row = 2)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self,bg='blue', width=430)
        print('got',self,master,args,kwargs)
        tk.Label(self, text="First Canvas").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Back to start-up page",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(StartUpPage)).pack()

        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame): # Sub-lcassing tk.Frame
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        # self is now an istance of tk.Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master, *args, **kwargs)
        # make a new Canvas whose parent is self.
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self,bg='yellow', width=430)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Second Canvas").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Back to start-up page",
              command=lambda: master.switch_Canvas(StartUpPage))

        self.button.pack()
        # pack the canvas inside the self (frame).
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
        #print('is instance',isinstance(self,tk.Frame))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**: **Visual Demo**

[image: demo]